# importing numpy in hackerrank competitions

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use numpy module for solving problems on hackerrank. But, when I imported numpy, it gave me the following error.

> ImportError: No module named 'numpy'.

I understand that this might be a very trivial question. But, I am a beginner in programming. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: They probably don't provide numpy. Usually only support for the standard library is provided for these websites.

Comment: This problem happens with pandas too. Using `import pandas`will get you `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`.

Answer (score 28):

I have run into the same issue on HackerRank. A number of their challenges do support NumPy--indeed, a handful *require* it. Either `import numpy` or the idiomatic `import numpy as np` will work just fine on those.

I believe you're simply trying to use numpy where they don't want you to. Because it's not part of the standard library, HackerRank would need to intentionally provide it. Where they do not, you will need to substitute lower-level, non-numpy code as a result.